# jQuery/Javascript Button Text Change (EDIT!)

Tags: javascript, jquery

EDIT!

I have a single button called "pc3LoadSELECT" that opens up a pop up with a new button called "loadCol_1" and loadCol_1 gets up to 150 options from local_storage.

What I need to work out is how to get "pc3LoadSELECT" label SELECT to change to whatever value is present in loadCol_1.

EG: If I choose 150 then the label SELECT will replace with 150.

The 2 set's of code I have played around with are:

```
$('a[dsid="pc3FitmentSELECT"]').text("");
```

&

```
var listOfLabels = ['loadCol_1'];

function getRandomLabel()
{
    return listOfLabels[Math.floor(Math.random() * listOfLabels.length) + 1];
}

$('a[dsid="pc3LoadSELECT"]').text("");
```

I will admit, in this 1 task I have been set, I am absolutely blind. So any help in attempting to work out or try to workout what is needed.

The data present isn't random and I shall attach an image which will show the range of options possible for this 1 button in the popup (a small sample).

Please advise?

[List of Possible Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBkqL.jpg)

Comment: put some code here  or in jsFiddle .

Comment: show what you have tried so far..there are many approach for this

Comment: I really need help, I have edited as suggested to provide more information, even attached a screenshot. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I created an example of a button that gets its value from an array.
Every time you open the popup you should set the button value from a list of options.

for that i created the function getRandomLabel();

hope that helps :)

```js
var listOfLabels = ['opt-1', 'opt-2', 'opt-3', 'opt-4', 'opt-5', 'opt-6'];


function getRandomLabel() {
  return listOfLabels[Math.floor(Math.random() * listOfLabels.length) + 1];
}




$('.randomize-label').click(function() {
  $('.btn1').html(getRandomLabel());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="randomize-label">Randomize Label</button>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<button class="btn1">SELECT</button>
```